# Webpack production build does not show user uploaded images (they appear in dev instead)

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

The question has this premise, maybe I am wrong about it:

- Running the build script Webpack creates a new dist folder with the
  dist files
- It creates an asset dir
- It fills the asset dir with images
  with new names like 123af34119.png so that they have different names
  and can be cached
- It loads those in the website according to the
  required page

When a user REPLACES or INSERTS a new uploaded image, the image is not uploaded in the dist folder, so until I build again, the image does not update or show.

1. Should I copy the uploaded image in the dist folder?
2. And with which name?
3. Should I use the "watch" property like a hot reload?
4. Is there any specific uploader I  should use?

I googled a lot but didn't find much.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to build the image into the source code? User input should probably not become a part of the website itself. Rather, you should upload the image to your server and serve it from there whenever it is requested. Imagine if you allowed the user to change some text on the page. Wouldn't it make more sense to create a dynamic field that pulls from some database or storage as opposed to rewriting the html?

Comment: The html is always the same, it is not rewritten. It loads an image that is precisely one unique image, let's say user101.jpg. When the user uploads a new one, it replaces user101.jpg in the server assets directory, not in the webpack dist directory. If I build webpack again, I see the user uploaded image updated. In development mode, it updates it with no problems and right away.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

Comment: The only solution I see from a change of perspective is using the "static" public folder,  but it wouldn't be into webpack. So the question would be: is the static folder the only solution?

Comment: You are in fact trying to rewrite the html, because the image src is changing from one build to the next. You also need the new file to get built into dist. It's likely working for you in dev because you have some sort of hot building going on. In prod, though, the src needs to change to the new image hash, and the file needs to get hashed and built into dist. Webpack won't do that dynamically; it's a one-time build process that you should run once, produce the files you need, and then deploy. That's why I suggested making the field dynamic and pulling in the file.

Comment: Maybe it's more straightforward to remove the image folder from the  bundle and put them into a static/public folder..

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had to make every user generated content to be out of the webpack production build, in a folder that in my case is named "static" and it is like a public folder where users may upload and replace their own images or contents.
The html always refers to that folder, and the user generated content is named always the same way in my case, so that x.jpg is replaced by a new x.jpg and not y.jpg. This makes the image uploaded to appear as soon as the user uploads it.
Thank you stellr42 for your suggestions and the discussion.